# Passing an array as an argument in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've been learning Ruby and am attempting a problem that takes an array of numbers as input, squares the integers at even positions in the array and then sums the squared integers + the integers at odd positions in the array. (1,2,3,4,5 should return 29). I got it to run, however, I'm having trouble passing in the numbers as an argument. Everytime I attempt to define the method and pass in the array when calling the method, I get an error.

**Basically, I want the method to be:**

`def alternate_sq_sum([])` and the ability to pass any array of numbers by calling the method.

```
Ex. alternate_sq_sum([1,4,63,2,1]).
```

**Here's my current code:**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
even = arr.select.each_with_index { |str,i| i.even? }
odd = arr.select.each_with_index {|str,i| i.odd? }

even_sum = 0
even.map do |n|
  even_sum +=n
end

odd_sum = 0
odd.map do |n|
  n*=n
  odd_sum+=n
end

print even_sum + odd_sum
```

Comment: Which error do you get? You should show the code you tried that caused the error; not just the part that works.

Comment: You just have to name the argument, for example `def alternate_sum(a)` and then use `a` as it it were an array, calling array methods on it. Maybe check whether it is an array at the beginning of the method

Comment: Sorry if I was too brief. I was getting a syntax error stating that I couldn't pass in array like this ... def arr([a]). Then, I tried to add the splat * and that didn't work. Then I removed the brackets and splat and it finally worked. I was also missing an end to the method. Any reason why splat and brackets don't work? I'm confused.

Comment: Also the code that worked was: `def alternate_sq_sum(a)` and calling it like so `alternate_sq_sum([1,2,3,4,5])` so thanks @blueygh2 :). Does anyone know why the splat argument doesn't work here?

Comment: @dwhipple you need *named* arguments, passing a type such as `[]` for *array* doesn't work. you can't tell ruby what type the arguments are, so you better choose good names like *arr* for array

Comment: @dwhipple also, splat doesnt work because without splat it wouldn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to thank everyone for the replies and post the code that worked. It appears I had [] inside where the argument would be and was missing an end that was causing it to fail.

```
def alternate_sq_sum(a)
  even = a.select.each_with_index { |str,i| i.even? }
  odd = a.select.each_with_index {|str,i| i.odd? }

  even_sum = 0
  even.map do |n|
    even_sum +=n
  end

  odd_sum = 0
  odd.map do |n|
    n*=n
    odd_sum+=n
  end

  total = even_sum + odd_sum
  total
end

alternate_sq_sum([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing is still unclear: we have to take squares of integers at even positions but you take squares of odds and this code works! But method even returns **true** if int is an even.